# ios share extension icon don't appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, share

My share extension do not work when open safari, gallery and etc.
I set my plist extension rule , but does not appear extension icon.
I need the extension, but does not work my extension.

this is my setting list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>share1</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.frogxy.extensionTest001.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>XPC!</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>TRUEPREDICATE</string>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

i think one thing, setting.
can you help me?

[1](https://goo.gl/X8SjGG) is my excuting video.

Comment: Does it work on a device? I have seen a bug where the icon shows up properly on devices, but not in the simulator.

Comment: Even when I downloaded it on my device from the app store, icon doesn't show.